# Is there a function to find the difference between datetimes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes which can have the same timestamps ( also +-1second) that have milliseconds in them. So when they are all together in the new dataframe i want to filter out the rows where they are more than 1 second different from each other

Is there a function similar to `dftogether['unique'] = np.ediff1d(dftogether['DateTime']` that works with timestamps?

My current solution works, but I am looking for a proper way to do it.
Let's say i have 3 dataframes, `df1`, `df2` and `df3`. For each dataframe I do this:

```
df1['DateTime'] = df1['DateTime'].apply(lambda 
x: x.strftime('%Y%d%m%H%M%S'))
df1['DateTime']= df1['DateTime'].astype(np.int64)
```

Which turns my `DateTime` into `int` so i can do this:

```
dftogether= pd.concat(z, sort=True)
dftogether= dftogether.sort_values('DateTime')
dftogether['unique'] = np.ediff1d(dftogether['DateTime'], to_begin=20181211150613411) <1
dftogether= dftogether[dftogether.unique == False]
```

And then I convert the `int` back to `datetime`

```
 dftogether['DateTime'] = dftogether['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%d%m%H%M%S'))
```

I couldn't figure out how to create sample data for the timestamps so i will just copypaste parts of the dataframe.

df1

```
737    2018-12-18 12:37:19.717
738    2018-12-18 12:37:21.936
739    2018-12-18 12:37:22.841
740    2018-12-18 12:37:23.144
877    2018-12-18 12:40:53.268
878    2018-12-18 12:40:56.597
879    2018-12-18 12:40:56.899
880    2018-12-18 12:40:57.300
968    2018-12-18 12:43:31.411
969    2018-12-18 12:43:36.150
970    2018-12-18 12:43:36.452
```

df2

```
691    2018-12-18 12:35:23.612
692    2018-12-18 12:35:25.627
788    2018-12-18 12:38:33.248
789    2018-12-18 12:38:33.553
790    2018-12-18 12:38:34.759
866    2018-12-18 12:40:29.487
867    2018-12-18 12:40:31.199
868    2018-12-18 12:40:32.206
```

df3

```
699    2018-12-18 12:35:42.452
701    2018-12-18 12:35:45.081
727    2018-12-18 12:36:47.466
730    2018-12-18 12:36:51.796
741    2018-12-18 12:37:23.448
881    2018-12-18 12:40:57.603
910    2018-12-18 12:42:02.904
971    2018-12-18 12:43:37.361
```

I want the `dftogether` to look like this but with timestamps instead of ints

```
   Unique  DateTime
 737    False  20181812123719
 738    False  20181812123721
 739    False  20181812123722
 741    False  20181812123723
 742     True  20181812123723
 740     True  20181812123723
 785    False  20181812123830
 786    False  20181812123831
 787    False  20181812123832
 787     True  20181812123832
 788    False  20181812123833
```

so I can drop the ones where `Unique == True`

```
 785    False 2018-12-18 12:38:30
 786    False 2018-12-18 12:38:31
 787    False 2018-12-18 12:38:32
 788    False 2018-12-18 12:38:33
 790    False 2018-12-18 12:38:34
 812    False 2018-12-18 12:39:10
 813    False 2018-12-18 12:39:11
```

Something else: Where can I voice my opinion on the new stackoverflow ask a question? IMO this is really awful, it keeps scrolling up, entering/copypasting code is really confusing now and all the For Example is really distracting. It took me more than 30 minutes to write this question

Comment: For something else part ..go to meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this, where your initial columns are a and b - is this what you needed?

```
from datetime import timedelta
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df = df.sort_values('b')
df['s'] = df['b'].shift()
df['d'] = df['b'] - df['s'] 
df['f'] = df['d'] < timedelta(0, 1)
print(df)
```

result:

```
      a                       b                       s               d      f
0   691 2018-12-18 12:35:23.612                     NaT             NaT  False
1   692 2018-12-18 12:35:25.627 2018-12-18 12:35:23.612 00:00:02.015000  False
0   699 2018-12-18 12:35:42.452 2018-12-18 12:35:25.627 00:00:16.825000  False
1   701 2018-12-18 12:35:45.081 2018-12-18 12:35:42.452 00:00:02.629000  False
2   727 2018-12-18 12:36:47.466 2018-12-18 12:35:45.081 00:01:02.385000  False
3   730 2018-12-18 12:36:51.796 2018-12-18 12:36:47.466 00:00:04.330000  False
0   737 2018-12-18 12:37:19.717 2018-12-18 12:36:51.796 00:00:27.921000  False
1   738 2018-12-18 12:37:21.936 2018-12-18 12:37:19.717 00:00:02.219000  False
2   739 2018-12-18 12:37:22.841 2018-12-18 12:37:21.936 00:00:00.905000   True
3   740 2018-12-18 12:37:23.144 2018-12-18 12:37:22.841 00:00:00.303000   True
4   741 2018-12-18 12:37:23.448 2018-12-18 12:37:23.144 00:00:00.304000   True
2   788 2018-12-18 12:38:33.248 2018-12-18 12:37:23.448 00:01:09.800000  False
3   789 2018-12-18 12:38:33.553 2018-12-18 12:38:33.248 00:00:00.305000   True
4   790 2018-12-18 12:38:34.759 2018-12-18 12:38:33.553 00:00:01.206000  False
5   866 2018-12-18 12:40:29.487 2018-12-18 12:38:34.759 00:01:54.728000  False
6   867 2018-12-18 12:40:31.199 2018-12-18 12:40:29.487 00:00:01.712000  False
7   868 2018-12-18 12:40:32.206 2018-12-18 12:40:31.199 00:00:01.007000  False
4   877 2018-12-18 12:40:53.268 2018-12-18 12:40:32.206 00:00:21.062000  False
5   878 2018-12-18 12:40:56.597 2018-12-18 12:40:53.268 00:00:03.329000  False
6   879 2018-12-18 12:40:56.899 2018-12-18 12:40:56.597 00:00:00.302000   True
7   880 2018-12-18 12:40:57.300 2018-12-18 12:40:56.899 00:00:00.401000   True
5   881 2018-12-18 12:40:57.603 2018-12-18 12:40:57.300 00:00:00.303000   True
6   910 2018-12-18 12:42:02.904 2018-12-18 12:40:57.603 00:01:05.301000  False
8   968 2018-12-18 12:43:31.411 2018-12-18 12:42:02.904 00:01:28.507000  False
9   969 2018-12-18 12:43:36.150 2018-12-18 12:43:31.411 00:00:04.739000  False
10  970 2018-12-18 12:43:36.452 2018-12-18 12:43:36.150 00:00:00.302000   True
7   971 2018-12-18 12:43:37.361 2018-12-18 12:43:36.452 00:00:00.909000   True
```

Comment: The speed is about the same your solution is a little faster, but does look a whole lot prettier. Marking as answered!

Answer (score 2):

I joined your df1 and df2 to a df, and created a dates list like this:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values('DateTime').reset_index(drop=True)

date_list = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for i in df.DateTime.tolist()]
```

then I get the desired output with a 1 liner:

```
df[[x>1 for x in [0]+[(j-i).total_seconds() for i,j in zip(date_list, date_list[1:])]]]
```

To understand how it works, first check the output of:

```
[x>1 for x in [0]+[(j-i).total_seconds() for i,j in zip(date_list, date_list[1:])]]
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I get this error `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp` i don't need to convert to strings first right?

Comment: Or do the timestamps still need to be `int`?

Comment: Your dates are already of type Timestamp, so yes, you need to skip the conversion step.

Comment: The type of my `dftogether['DateTime]` is `datetime64[ns]`,they need to be of type `timestamp` before your `date_list` works i assume? ( I shouldn't have said that i wanted timestamps instead of ints in my original post )

Comment: Try running the df[........] command, changing the date_list with df.DateTime.tolist().

Comment: I am still no quite sure how to fix it. what I did now ( i assume you meant this ). `dffouten['DateTime'] = dffouten.DateTime.tolist()` before the `date_list`

Comment: From the code you posted, I assume DateTime is already a column in your dataframe. Is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185606/discussion-between-martijn-van-amsterdam-and-neofytos-boufidis).